# Python doesn't save the value of a simple variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm trying to run this code in Python. (I omitted the body of the 'listAccounts' function because I have no problem with that)

```
import os

customers = []
numAccounts = 0
option = 0

def listAccounts(customers):
    (...)

def createAccount(customers, numAccounts):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    lastname = input('Enter a lastname: ')
    account = {'name':name, 'lastname':lastname, 'account':{'balance':0, 'accountNumber':numAccounts}}
    customers.append(account)
    numAccounts += 1
    print("Account created")
    input("Press Intro to continue...")
    return customers, numAccounts

while ('3' != option):
    option = input('''Please select an option: 
    1.- List Accounts
    2.- Create Account
    3.- Exit
    ''')

    if option == '1':
        listAccounts(customers)
    elif opcion == '2':
        createAccount(customers, numAccounts)
    os.system("CLS")
print("End of the program")
```

The problem is when I create a new account with the 'createAccount' function. Everything works fine when I enter the values and saves it. I show the accounts and the first account number is 0. Everything is going well, but when I create a new account again and list them, I realize that both accounts have the number 0, even if I create a third account this has the value 0. Like if the 'numAccounts' variable is not increasing.

I debuged my program, and I notice that the value of 'numAccounts' really increases to 1, but when step to the 'return' line, it puts the value in 0 again. I comment the 'return' line, change the values, etc. But nothing works. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the scope of the numAccounts variable, you defined your functions as createAccount(customers, numAccounts), that means that the numAccounts variable you're increasing by one is only alive inside the function. As you defined numAccounts variable as global you can defined your function like createAccount(customers, currentnumAccounts) and when you call the numAccounts+=numAccounts you're going to increase the global variable.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Genaro. I read more about the behavior of variables in functions, and I have solved it adding the 'global' keyword inside the 'createAccount' function, so in this way I could save the value when it increases. Thank you people for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not storing what is returned by `createAccount`.

Though you have created your all variables at global level, you are receiving variables with same name so function will make a local copy of that variable and it would not change the global variable's value.

Your while loop should be as below

```
while ('3' != option):
    option = input('''Please select an option: 
    1.- List Accounts
    2.- Create Account
    3.- Exit
    ''')

    if option == '1':
        listAccounts(customers)
    elif opcion == '2':
        customers,numAccounts = createAccount(customers, numAccounts)
    os.system("CLS")
print("End of the program")
```